# Display image from ViewModel

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, image, viewmodel

In my .Net MVC3 application, I am storing a few images into a SQL Server database (they are .png files).  I would really like to stick with this method if possible, because I prefer working with a database to working with a filesystem (it's a small page, and nobody will notice a performance issue).

Storing the image into the database seems to be no problem.  Retrieving the data back out is not a problem either.  What I'm having trouble with is displaying the image in a view.

The image is stored in a SQL Server database as a Varbinary(max).  The View Model uses a Byte[] to hold the information.  The View Model has other data stored in it, but as far as the image is concerned, here's what I've done:

controller:

```
ViewModel data = Repository.GetData();

//data now holds all of the information that I need for my view
//data.Image is of type Byte[], and it holds the image I am having trouble displaying.

return View(data);
```

View

```
@model = data
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.x)  @*works*@
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image)  @*no good*@
```

**Does the image need to be stored as a temp file in order for this to work?**
If so, it seems like storing the image in the database is just a big waste of time.

If I return a FileStreamResult as my model:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, Open, Read);
return View(new FileStreamResult(fs, "image/png"));
```

....and I change my View's model to be "FileStreamResult," I can still find no way to display the image.

But if I return a FileStreamResult like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, Open, Read);
return new FileStreamResult(fs, "image/png");
```

then the image is displayed (but I think this is just the browser "opening" that file, not "rendering" it as html).

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic already, but I've looked at them.  I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding of the web or mvc or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option 1) [ASP.NET MVC Custom Image Action](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx)
- Option 2) In your view

  `< img src="loadimage?id=@Model.Id"/>`

And your controller:

```
    public ActionResult LoadImage(int id)
    {
        // load the image from the database and return the filestream
    }
```

Comment: Excellent.  I used Option 2, and it works fine.  The LoadImage action on my controller is returning a FileContentResult, and the image is displayed.  Thank you.